# Is there a test coverage requirement for 2GP Unlocked package?

Tags: unmanaged-package

[From here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_writing_tests.htm) we learn of the 75% coverage requirement for any package that is to be published on App Exchange

> In addition, before you deploy Apex or package it for the AppExchange,
>   the following must be true.
>
> • Unit tests must cover at least 75% of your Apex code, and all of those tests must complete successfully.

I'm under the impression that my private 2GP packages are not under the same requirement. Am I right?

Comment: According to Salesforce, you need to test it. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_build_release_artifact.htm?search_text=test

Comment: Thank you @ProlayChaudhury, but if my 2GP is only going to be deployed to my org (not intended for App Exchange) I still don't see this requirement specified. Like here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_best_practices.htm?search_text=test

Comment: Leaving that aside, how can anyone be happy to deploy untested code?

Comment: There's no happiness in deploying untested code. But, I'm not happy with an inflexible requirement. We have other kinds of tests that tell us if the apex we deploy is working

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_code_coverage.htm) says:

> Although code coverage isn’t enforced for unlocked packages, it’s a best practice to include Apex tests in your unlocked packages.

---

**Update:**

75% code coverage will be enforced for promoting an Unlocked Package beginning with Winter '21:
[Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_get_ready_code_coverage.htm)

Comment: Revisiting this a few months later: so far it seems to me that requirement for tests *is* enforced for unlocked packages

Comment: @bkwdesign can you elaborate on your experience?